# Decrease x-axis label density in highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a question about Highcharts.

This is my chart:

[image]

I want to decrease label of x-axis density, like y-axis.

Thanks so much for your helps.

Edit: for example: http:// jsfiddle.net /vuek2teg/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `xAxis.tickInterval`.

```
  xAxis: {
    tickInterval: 20,
    (...)
  }
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4a6snbqe/

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickInterval

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `step` property of the `xAxis` labels:

```
xAxis: {
        labels: {
            step: 5 // number to skip
        }
    },
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/shanabus/rc21k44g/

Documentation: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.step

Comment: I think it's not for me, i don't use auto datetime, i use two datas for x and y axises, when i use step feature, i get such output:

Comment: You may need to increase your step value then.  I adjusted your jsfiddle to use "20" and it cleans out many of the labels: http://jsfiddle.net/shanabus/vuek2teg/3/